# Inconsistent behavior using wildcard with Directory.GetFiles on Mac via Mono

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I'm looking at some C# code that runs on both Windows and Mac via mono. On Windows we specify the parameters like so:

```
Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Path", "Subfolder\\*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

As expected that gives you all of the files in C:\Path\Subfolder. But on Mac we have something like:

```
Directory.GetFiles("/Users/Path", "Subfolder/*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

which throws an exception:

```
DirectoryNotFoundException - Directory 'Users/Path/Subfolder/Subfolder' not found.
```

Do you think this is a problem with Mono or is the search pattern not really the correct way to do this and it somehow works on Windows but not Mac?

The code its being used in is to build up a list of files to exclude from another list of files, so in most cases the searchpattern is something like "filename" or "*.jpg". That seems kind of wasteful to me and it would be better to just apply these exclusion strings to the list of files but it's used in a lot of places so I don't want to change existing behaviour in any way.

Comment: The source code is here, so you might take a deeper look, https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs

Comment: Following through their code I can see that it falls down in ValidateDirectoryListing due to the combination of path and search pattern resulting in a new directory that doesn't exist. Discussed it with someone here and it seems like the mono implementation might be technically correct and Windows is just being more lax?

Comment: try Directory.GetFiles("/Users/Path/Subfolder", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Comment: That's effectively what I've gone for but not at the point where GetFiles is actually being called. Since it was just being passed a set of paths and searchpatterns from elsewhere, there was no way to know if they could be combined like that.